# Why is my cronjob running another php version than in the browser?

Tags: php, cron

When I run a cronjob, the `PHP` version is:  `5.4.43`
when I run the same script script through browser the version is: 5.6.29

I need it to be php `version >=5.6` because else my script won't work

my webhost is justhost.

I have added these headers in my `.htaccess`
AddHandler `application/x-httpd-php56.php`

and I have updated the PHP `config` to use `PHP 5.6` with a single `php.ini` in `public_home` in `PHP config`, in cpanel

I am using this cronjob command:

```
/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php-cli -qc /home4/username/public_html/php.ini /home4/username/public_html/cronjon.php
```

the command php does not work, even though they say it does work on their website: `https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/168`

I have contacted tech support, but they can't help me.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Well, `/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php-cli` is clearly the path to a PHP 5.4 executable. Have you tried changing to `54` to `56`?

Comment: yes, I have. Without avail. I asked tech about this too, but they said I had to use this path.
I really hate my host, I think about switching.

Comment: If you've got access, I'd go looking in `/usr/php` for what other versions are available in there. Otherwise, yeah, a new host is probably in order.